# Computer suspends when not logged in

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, gdm

Since the latest update of Gnome / GDM my computer seems to be put into suspend mode when I am idle on the logon screen for about 20 minutes.

This was not the case before the update.
Current Version of gnome-session & gdm `3.28.0`. I'm running Arch Linux.

[The system log](https://gist.github.com/founderio/eb80bf4c0b2aa4978ca7080c3d68b1fa), centered around `Mar 29 17:21:17 oliver-desktop kernel: PM: suspend exit` +/- 200 lines. If you need more, let me know.

I have looked through a lot of the gsettings, none of the ones I tried were able to make gdm behave otherise.
Also, [the configuration documentation](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en) does not hint to any option related to auto-suspend.

Comment: I believe I ran into the same issue. It will suspend even during activity of an SSH or VNC session.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll find https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#GDM_auto-suspend_.28GNOME_3.28.29 useful.

> #### GDM auto-suspend (GNOME 3.28)
>
> GDM uses a separate dconf database to control power management. You can make GDM behave the same way as user sessions by copying the user settings to GDM's dconf database.
>
> `$ IFS=$'\n'; for x in $(sudo -u YOUR_USER gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power); do eval "sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gsettings set $x"; done; unset IFS`

Comment: I understand that you’re quoting, but, FYI, the `eval` is probably unnecessary.  (And `eval` is often harmful, so it’s best to avoid unnecessary ones, especially in conjunction with ``sudo``.)

Comment: Yup. And I don't know why the official wiki uses `eval`.

Comment: Can't test it right now, but this looks excactly like the type of edge case I have. Thank you so much!

Comment: Tested it now - Yes, it works!

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that attempting to do this from a terminal whithin a session that is running dbus already might cause issues. If you receive a message like `No protocol specified`, try running from a tty instead.
For the record, I manually changed the settings with `sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'` and `sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'nothing'` instead of the above `eval` method.

Comment: thanks, not a good default for servers that might have a gdm installed an sure don't want to go hibernated

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue on Debian testing (Debian 10 "Buster").

I found that this is independent of the power settings made by an unprivileged user within a Gnome login session. It also suspends during an active SSH or VNC session.

The offending settings can be printed to the console. As superuser:

```
su -s /bin/bash Debian-gdm
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

dbus-launch gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type
dbus-launch gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout
```

This prints 'suspend' and '1200', respectively.

To turn off suspension, set:

```
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type nothing
```

I also filed a Debian bug report here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=896083

Comment: For any Fedora family distro users out there, `dbus-launch` is provided by the package `dbus-x11`, as of time of writing.