# Automatically logged out of GNOME after inactivity

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome

I'm running Arch Linux and since a recent update I am automatically logged out of GNOME and all running processes are terminated (not screen lock, really logged out of my session).

After some more time, the computer suspends, which I solved according to this post:

[Computer suspends when not logged in](https://superuser.com/questions/1309219/computer-suspends-when-not-logged-in)

But this does not really solve the original problem of getting logged out.

What setting do I have to tweak to prevent GNOME from logging me out after inactivity?

Comment: Hmm happens to me as well recently. Wonder what's going on.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure it out? Having the exact same issue right now